# Replace require.js script tag via Grunt

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am working on a yeoman generator that is based on the fantastic webapp generator but handles some stuff bit different. One thing that I'd like to achieve is to get the require.js files as one file. This means that instead of this...

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

... I want to have this:

```
<script scr="scripts/main"></script>
```

From require.js, this is works with pretty much no effort.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // ...
        requireLib: '../bower_components/requirejs/require'
    }
});

require(['...', 'requireLib'], function (..., requireLib) {
    // ...
});
```

I am stuck on the Gruntfile.js part. What is the best way to get the script tag modified, e.g. have the value of data-main as new value of src and data-main deleted?

Comment: What is currently going on in your Gruntfile?

Comment: It is mostly the file `yo webapp` would write with some tiny modifications, see it here: [The Gist](https://gist.github.com/sontags/6813239)... The `build` Task should do the tag mashing job at the very end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by myself. Go for grunt-regex-replace:

```
npm install grunt-regex-replace --save-dev
```

And do this in Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // ...
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        // ...
        'regex-replace': {
            dist: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'],
                actions: [
                    {
                        name: 'requirejs-onefile',
                        search: '<script data-main=".*" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>',
                        replace: function(match){
                            var regex = /scripts\/.*main/;
                            var result = regex.exec(match);
                            return '<script src="' + result[0] + '.js"></script>';
                        },
                        flags: 'g'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Run this...

```
grunt regex-replace
```

... and you are done. That does the job pretty well...

Cheers

Comment: Glad to find this! I was stuck at the same step after starting a project with yo webapp. With all the issues I've found, I'm not sure that generator is ready for prime time.  Anyway this isn't working for me because the uglify and rev tasks are renaming the main.js to something like [random prefix].main.min.js, so it doesn't get picked up by the script. If I could figure out how to get the name of the outputted file I could modify it - I know the path and in my config there's only one .js file so I guess I could just search for it, but that seems brittle.